# fullcalendar event in modal dialog

Tags: modal-dialog, fullcalendar

I am trying to implement dialog windows for events in fullcalendar instead alert and prompt window in a easy way. Any example will be really apreciated.

```
   select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var title = bootbox.prompt("Hello World!", function(result) {
     if (result) {
     if (title) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   url: 'add_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
   bootbox.alert('Added Successfully');
   }
   });
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at some CSS/JS frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap or Zurb (there are others, some specifically for this kind of thing).  Generally, they will have Modals/Dialogs/alerts that can be called programmatically from JS.

e.g.

```
success: function(json) {    
   $(".alert").alert();    //Bootstrap alert popup
}
```

Comment: @S Farron I Have updated the code. I have used bootbox, but I think I am missed with callback. Thanks